# use func from another module java using spring

Tags: java, function, module

In my project there are some modules.
I want to use func from another module in my project.
I tried some ways to do this.
When I wrote:

```
studentManager studentMng =  new studentManager();
studentMng.createStudent(student);
```

in line 1, I can see that studentMng is null (in the debugger).
So I get `nullPointerException`.

All this code located under main func (public static void main(String[] args)
then if I use another option I get conflict about static.

What I have to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your studentManager Class. Always follow Java naming conventions - Class name should start with a  capital letter like StudentManager

Comment: Is it also null in line two? The debugger stop, before you call new studentManager()